# Effective algorithm to random 4 unique integers less than a big max such as 100_000

Tags: java, algorithm, random

Here is my try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Max 100_000
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomFour(100_000)));
}

public static int[] randomFour(int max) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] four = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        while (true) {
            // Random from 1 to max
            four[i] = 1 + (int) (r.nextFloat() * max);

            boolean dup = false; // check j: 0 -> i-1
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (four[j] == four[i]) {
                    dup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (dup == false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return four;
}
```

This implementation is working fine. Is there a better algorithm for this problem (both time & memory consuming), especially to a very big max number? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Also, how do you define "better"? Faster execution time? Less memory consumption? Readability? Cyclic complexity? LOC? Number of character?

Comment: this would be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Turing85: I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: If what you want is a random integer, why do you use nextFloat(), and not nextInt()? Start by reading the javadoc of Random.

Comment: Why not use `r.nextInt(max)`?

Comment: Also do you need to exclude duplicates?

Comment: @Nexevis: No duplicates.

Comment: @JB Nizet. Thanks for mentioning new api. I need 4 unique integers so I think nextInt does not solve duplicate issues.

Comment: I'm saying to use `nextInt(max)` instead of `nextFloat() * max` if you want integers...I'm aware it does not exclude duplicates.  Neither of them do.

Comment: @Loc it doesn't solve the non-duplicate issues, but why use nextFloat() when you want an int? It won't solve the dulicate issue either, but at least it will get you an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have an array of 4 distinct random integers between 1 and 100_000 (inclusive).

Here's a concise end expressive way of doing that

```
int[] four = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                     .ints(1, 100_001) // 1 is inclusive, 100_001 is exclusive
                     .distinct()
                     .limit(4)
                     .toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for a concise way!